# AngularJS app not rendering properly in IE 8 for multiple reasons

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-directive

I have been working on a portfolio site called [maxmythic.com](http://maxmythic.com/) using AngularJS and have managed to get it to show up good in everything but IE 8 and 7 (I'm not even bothering with IE 6). I even added all the IE8 AngularJS fixes found http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie and  http://henriquat.re/appendix/angularjs-and-ie8/necessary-changes-for-ie8-compatibility.html I thought those fixes would make it work but its seems like nothing changed.

At http://maxmythic.com/ and http://maxmythic.com/design, a 3 x 6 grid of 'design tile' divs (with titles and background images) are supposed to display. It gets created by `ng-repeat` in the Angular view called `design.html`

```
<section ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="main">
  <a href="#" ng-repeat="tile in designTiles" ng-href="{{tile.url}}" class="{{tile.bgImageClass}}">
    <div ng-mouseenter="blankBar='blueBar'" ng-mouseleave="blankBar = 'blankBar'" class="tile-info">
    <div class="blankBar" ng-class="blankBar"></div>
      <h3 class="tile_title">{{tile.title}}</h3>
    </div>
  </a>
</section>
```

In IE 8, ngRepeat will seem to overwrite each design tile div with the next design tile div in the order they appear in my `designTile` object list

```
angular.module('maxmythicApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.designTiles = [
      {
        url : '/design/vance-and-gary-unhinged',
        bgImageClass : 'vance-and-gary-unhinged',
        title : 'Vance & Gary Unhinged',
        // use : 'Album Art'
      },
      {
        url : '/design/dam-funk',
        bgImageClass : 'dam-funk',
        title : 'Dam-Funk',
        // use : 'Logo'
      },
      .....
      .....
      .....
      {
        url : '/design/various-sketches',
        bgImageClass : 'various-sketches',
        title : 'Various Sketches',
        // use : 'Logo'
      },
      {
        url : '/design/maxmythic-dot-com',
        bgImageClass : 'maxmythic-dot-com',
        title : 'maxmythic.com',
        // use : 'Logo'
      },
    ];
  });
```

As the page is loading, I can see the first one appear but, as soon as it appears, it gets replaced by the next one. Only one design tile div is ever seen at one time and ultimately the last design tile equates to the last object in the the `designTile` list which is:

```
{
  url : '/design/maxmythic-dot-com',
  bgImageClass : 'maxmythic-dot-com',
  title : 'maxmythic.com',
},
```

If I look into IE's developer tools HTML tab I see what seems to be a messed up out of order DOM and look, you can see all the 18 design tile divs displayed there. It all looks like this

[image]

So none of the design tiles show up there but if I look at the original source it looks totally different. In fact, the `<section>` element that contains the list of design tile divs does not even appear.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>/\/\/\</title>
    <meta name="fragment" content="!">
    <meta name="description" content="Max Mythic : Designer & Front-end Developer">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon-iphone.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon-ipad.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-icon-iphone4.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="apple-touch-icon-retina.png">  
    <link href="favicon_32x32.ico" rel="icon">      
    <!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="mm_favicon_32x32.ico"><![endif]-->
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="apple-touch-icon-retina.png">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <base href="/">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/aff564d2.main.css">
  </head>
  <body id="ng-app" ng-app="maxmythicApp">

    <div id="page">
      <header>
        <h1 class="logo">
          Max Mythic : Designer, Illustrator & Developer
          <a href="/">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 97 27.623"><path d="M97 27.623h-3.73c-3.687 0-6.687-4.524-8.917-13.448C82.29 5.9 79.8 3 78.3 3c-1.481 0-3.943 2.927-6.006 11.2 c-2.23 8.923-5.23 13.448-8.916 13.448s-6.687-4.524-8.918-13.448C52.444 5.9 50 3 48.5 3c-1.482 0-3.944 2.927-6.006 11.2 c-2.23 8.923-5.23 13.448-8.917 13.448s-6.686-4.524-8.916-13.448C22.598 5.9 20.1 3 18.7 3s-3.944 2.927-6.006 11.2 c-2.23 8.923-5.23 13.448-8.917 13.448H0v-3h3.73c1.482 0 3.945-2.927 6.007-11.175C11.968 4.5 15 0 18.7 0 s6.686 4.5 8.9 13.448c2.062 8.2 4.5 11.2 6 11.175c1.482 0 3.945-2.927 6.007-11.175C41.814 4.5 44.8 0 48.5 0 c3.687 0 6.7 4.5 8.9 13.448c2.063 8.2 4.5 11.2 6 11.175c1.481 0 3.943-2.927 6.006-11.175 C71.66 4.5 74.7 0 78.3 0c3.687 0 6.7 4.5 8.9 13.448c2.063 8.2 4.5 11.2 6 11.175H97V27.623z"></svg>
          </a>
        </h1>
        <nav class="pagenav" role="navigation">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="/design">
                design
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/about">
                about
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/contact">
                contact
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- <div class="navicon">Nav Icon</div> -->
      </header>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="chromeframe">You are using an outdated browser. <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade your browser today</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install Google Chrome Frame</a> to better experience this site.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
      <script src="components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
      <div class="container" ng-view=""></div>
      <div id="layout_footer"></div>
    </div>
    <footer role="footer" id="footer">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="icon" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/maxmythic">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 30 30"><path d="M13.359,14.948H9.168c0,6.7,0,14.949,0,14.949H2.955c0,0,0-8.165,0-14.949H0V9.671h2.955V6.25 c0-2.448,1.162-6.269,6.271-6.269L13.827,0v5.126c0,0-2.798,0-3.34,0c-0.545,0-1.317,0.271-1.317,1.437v3.109h4.736L13.359,14.948z"></svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="icon" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/maxmythic">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 30.246 24.584"><path d="M27.149 6.125c0.015 0.3 0 0.5 0 0.803c0 8.201-6.242 17.656-17.657 17.656c-3.504 0-6.768-1.027-9.513-2.787 c0.484 0.1 1 0.1 1.5 0.086c2.908 0 5.584-0.992 7.707-2.656c-2.715-0.051-5.006-1.846-5.796-4.311 c0.378 0.1 0.8 0.1 1.2 0.109c0.566 0 1.114-0.072 1.635-0.217c-2.84-0.568-4.979-3.08-4.979-6.084 c0-0.025 0-0.053 0.001-0.08C2.05 9.1 3 9.4 4 9.422C2.358 8.3 1.3 6.4 1.3 4.3 c0-1.137 0.306-2.204 0.84-3.12C5.166 4.9 9.7 7.4 14.9 7.619c-0.104-0.453-0.161-0.93-0.161-1.414 C14.734 2.8 17.5 0 20.9 0c1.785 0 3.4 0.8 4.5 1.959c1.414-0.277 2.742-0.795 3.94-1.506 c-0.465 1.449-1.446 2.666-2.729 3.433c1.258-0.149 2.453-0.483 3.565-0.977C29.417 4.2 28.4 5.2 27.1 6.125z"></svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="icon" target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/113556551990494099731">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 28.939 29.768"><path d="M15.263 16.994l-1.396-1.084c-0.426-0.354-1.007-0.818-1.007-1.67c0-0.855 0.581-1.399 1.086-1.903 c1.626-1.28 3.251-2.642 3.251-5.513c0-2.952-1.856-4.504-2.748-5.241h2.4L19.368 0h-7.633c-2.094 0-5.111 0.496-7.32 2.3 c-1.666 1.437-2.479 3.418-2.479 5.2c0 3 2.3 6.1 6.4 6.098c0.389 0 0.813-0.038 1.238-0.078 c-0.191 0.466-0.386 0.854-0.386 1.515c0 1.2 0.6 1.9 1.2 2.637c-1.744 0.121-5 0.314-7.4 1.8 C0.694 20.8 0 22.8 0 24.215c0 2.9 2.7 5.6 8.3 5.553c6.662 0 10.189-3.688 10.189-7.336 C18.517 19.8 17 18.4 15.3 16.994z M10.188 12.529c-3.333 0-4.843-4.31-4.843-6.908c0-1.012 0.19-2.058 0.851-2.874 C6.818 2 7.9 1.5 8.9 1.465c3.214 0 4.9 4.3 4.9 7.143c0 0.7-0.077 1.939-0.969 2.8 C12.198 12.1 11.2 12.5 10.2 12.529z M10.227 28.14c-4.145 0-6.817-1.981-6.817-4.74c0-2.756 2.479-3.688 3.331-3.995 c1.626-0.548 3.72-0.623 4.067-0.623c0.388 0 0.6 0 0.9 0.039c2.946 2.1 4.2 3.1 4.2 5.1 C15.923 26.3 13.9 28.1 10.2 28.14z"><polygon points="25,12.5 25,8.6 23.1,8.6 23.1,12.5 19.3,12.5 19.3,14.4 23.1,14.4 23.1,18.3 25,18.3 25,14.4 28.9,14.4 28.9,12.5"></svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="madeby">
          <p>Made by</p>
          <svg class="maxmythic" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 97 27.623"><style>.style0{fill:#666666;}</style><path d="M97 27.623h-3.73c-3.687 0-6.687-4.524-8.917-13.448C82.29 5.9 79.8 3 78.3 3c-1.481 0-3.943 2.927-6.006 11.2 c-2.23 8.923-5.23 13.448-8.916 13.448s-6.687-4.524-8.918-13.448C52.444 5.9 50 3 48.5 3c-1.482 0-3.944 2.927-6.006 11.2 c-2.23 8.923-5.23 13.448-8.917 13.448s-6.686-4.524-8.916-13.448C22.598 5.9 20.1 3 18.7 3s-3.944 2.927-6.006 11.2 c-2.23 8.923-5.23 13.448-8.917 13.448H0v-3h3.73c1.482 0 3.945-2.927 6.007-11.175C11.968 4.5 15 0 18.7 0 s6.686 4.5 8.9 13.448c2.062 8.2 4.5 11.2 6 11.175c1.482 0 3.945-2.927 6.007-11.175C41.814 4.5 44.8 0 48.5 0 c3.687 0 6.7 4.5 8.9 13.448c2.063 8.2 4.5 11.2 6 11.175c1.481 0 3.943-2.927 6.006-11.175 C71.66 4.5 74.7 0 78.3 0c3.687 0 6.7 4.5 8.9 13.448c2.063 8.2 4.5 11.2 6 11.175H97V27.623z" class="style0"></svg>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </footer>


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/cdf6190d.scripts.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
    <script>
      var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-37437533-1'],['_trackPageview']];
      (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
      g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Additionally, IE 8 throws the following error

```
TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'childNodes': object is null or undefinedundefined
```

Another funny thing is that if I enter `http://maxmythic.com` into the address bar, IE8 will add a `#` (hashtag) turning that original URL into `http://maxmythic.com/#/`. This screws up the pretty URL structure I had going with HTML5 mode.

On top of all of that 98% of my CSS is not being applied to the html. Maybe that is a separate question all together but I thought I'd mention it just in case anyone had run into all of these issues before and had a solution.

All of the site's files can be viewed at my gh-pages repo here 
https://github.com/siddhion/maxmythic/tree/gh-pages

**Any ideas on what is going on here and how to solve it?**

Answer (score 7):

I am working on a AngularJs project at the moment and we also need to give support to IE8.

Everything is working fine as expected.

I took a look at your code and I can see you have included few things to make AngularJs work with IE 8.

But at the same time I think you missed some bits, so it's worthwhile take a look again at [this page - AngularJs IE](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

As we are dealing with a really **[unreliable](http://theie8countdown.com/)** browser as IE 8, I would strongly suggest you to follow the instructions on the page word by word.

For example: I didn't find this line on your code above
`<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">`

You also wrote this line
`<body id="ng-app" ng-app="maxmythicApp">`

BUT the official page suggests this format:
`<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="optionalModuleName">`

And you put the **ng-app** inside the `<body>` tag instead of the `<html>`.

These details might not make a big difference for modern (and decent) browsers, but we are talking about [IE 8](http://theie8countdown.com/) so every little details does matter - ('**play by the book**').

**About the hash(#**), that's a normal behaviour of AngularJs.
AngularJS offers two configuration modes to control the format of the URL: **Hashbang mode** (the default) and the **HTML5 mode** which is based on using the HTML5 History API.

IE8 clearly doesn't support HTML 5 history API so the Hashbang mode is used instead.

You can read about all of this [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips but it did not change a thing. In fact I don't think it is a problem with IE8 reading AngularJS code because as I mentioned above, all my DIVs are being loaded fine. They just show up one on top of the other in the same place. The problem seems to be that the CSS is just not being applied to the elements properly. I have started to write a new style sheet targeted for IE8 only.

Comment: I had few issues to make it work with IE 8 in the beginning, but once I followed the same rules I told you above everything now works fine.
I understand what you mean about _italic_'all my DIVs are being loaded fine'_italic_ - it seems nothing is broken, no error message, but it's just not displaying the content you need. Really hard and frustrating to debug with IE8.
I'm quite interested to know if you manage to find a solution for that in case IE 8 starts to break something here.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add that the /# being added to your URLs will happen in IE8 as IE8 does not support HTML5 pushState APIs and so it uses a fallback hash fragment mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem, i clear all DOM's class and id, just clear all jquery event listener .maybe some jquery function execute before angular script was rendered. therefore ng-repeat can't work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the trailing comma in your $scope.designTiles array.

IE8 will always use the hashtag in html5 mode, as others have stated.