# Angular JS and IE8

Tags: angularjs

I've taken a look at the docs:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

And another question on the subject:

[AngularJS app not rendering properly in IE 8 for multiple reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476434/angularjs-app-not-rendering-properly-in-ie-8-for-multiple-reasons)

But my page still doesn't work in IE8.

Here's what I've done:

At the top of my page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="myApp">
```

In my head:

```
 <!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script src="/js/json3.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

Am I missing something? i'm not using any custom element tags.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: No module: myApp. How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular.js: Uncaught error, no module: myapp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283291/angular-js-uncaught-error-no-module-myapp)

Comment: It's not a duplication, I've read that thread and its not the same question.

Answer (score 0):

- Load your web application in IE 8 and using developer tools in IE8 see whether there are any
  Console errors. If there is any console error, please post those
  errors here. It is better if you can upload screen shots of console errors
- If you use the $http.delete api call in your script file to replace it
  $http ["delete"]